# D3 Chloropleth zoom works when only with states, but breaks when I draw it with counties

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

I have something similar to Mike Bostock’s [Zoom to Bounding](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541/) in my code, however I wanted to add the ability to also drag/mousewheel zoom. Getting that working was fine, however I would end up in the situation where the svg transform/translate to zoom wouldn't play well with mousewheel zoom, because the mousehwheel zoom wouldnt be aware of the scale of the zooming as done in Mikes example.

So to fix this I try to make the click function use the zoom event also. This works fine on some parts of the map but not others and I dont know why. An example displaying what I am talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/72g1wL0t/8/

The west hand side of the map seems to work fine when clicking on it. However if you move over to the east coast, it all goes to hell.

Even stranger, if I change the line that is drawing counties in the jsfiddle to be us.objects.states and just draw the states, the zoom then works fine for the whole map.

Anyone give me any guidance here? I know some of the zooming stuff in d3v4 would probably be the better way to do this, but I am stuck on d3v3.

```
    var bounds = path.bounds(d),

        dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
        dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
        x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
        y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2;
    var scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height);
    var translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];


    svg.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(zoom.translate(translate)
            .scale(scale).event);
```

Answer (score 0):

So by more closely following this example here: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/9656675

I was able to get the desired functionality working.